# How to extract the string between dash (-) and dot (.) in asp classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Could somebody help me to extract the string between dash (-) and dot (.) at the last of URL in ASP classic?

For example:

```
mypizza.com/this-is-my-special-6-pizza-this-week-3256.html
```

How can I extract the `3256` value?
PS: There are many dashes and some numbers appear in URL.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you definitely have a dash before the number. If you could have a / before the number then add another replace for / into -.

```
dim s, aSplit
s = "mypizza.com/this-is-my-special-6-pizza-this-week-3256.html"
s = replace(s, ".", "-")   ' replace any dots with dashes

aSplit = split(s, "-") ' break s into an array, splitting at dashes. Note it is a zero-based array.

dim sOut
sOut = aSplit(ubound(aSplit) - 1) ' get the penultimate entry in the array
```

Comment: There is no len for arrays in VBScript. Use UBound() to get the last index, and substract 1 to get the penultimate item.

Comment: Thanks @Ekkehard.Horner, corrected incorrect use of len and accuracy of penultimate selection.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I found the answer:

```
Dim n, strPost
dashCount = len(urlPost)-len(replace(urlPost,"-","")) 
n=dashCount
thisURL=split(urlPost,"-")
strPost=replace(thisURL(n),".html","")
response.write(strPost)
```